# Calculate integrals: a) $\frac{d}{dx}\int_{5x-1}^{x^3}x\cdot(3\sin t+2\ln t)dt$ and b) $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(\int_{2}^{\cos x}(2t+\sin t)dt)$

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I am struggling with integral questions. Any help with the integration of these two functions? What technique should be used?

Calculate:

a) $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}\int_{5x-1}^{x^3}x\cdot(3\sin t+2\ln t)dt$

b) $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}\ln\left(\int_{2}^{\cos x}(2t+\sin t)dt\right)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In order to get responses that suit your needs, please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Leibniz's Rule: If $$F(x)=\int_{\psi {(x)}}^{\phi {(x)}}g(x,t)dt$$ then $$F'(x)=g(x,\phi {(x)})\phi '(x)-g(x,\psi (x))\psi '(x)+\int_{\psi (x)}^{\phi (x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x,t)dt$$ Note that in (b) two of the three expressions on the right are 0.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways. First, you can calculate the integrals. Just split the terms. For example, write the first expression as $$\frac {d}{dx}\left[3x\int_{5x-1}^{x^3}\sin t dt+2x\int_{5x-1}^{x^3}\ln t dt\right]$$
You now have two simpler integrals.

The second option involves the second theorem of calculus and the chain rule, and it was answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781398/derivative-of-integral-with-variable-bounds/781433).