# A question about interchanging an improper integral and a limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-explanation, improper-integrals

I was reading this article https://brilliant.org/wiki/integration-tricks/#differentiation-under-the-integral-sign and I didn't understand what allows them in the second example (the one where they compute $\int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x}$) to put $\lim\limits_{a\to \infty}$ under the integral sign. What theorem is this?
EDIT : The specific part I have trouble understanding is why $\lim \limits_{a \to \infty} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-ax} \frac{\sin x} {x} dx= \int_0^{\infty} \lim \limits_{a \to \infty} e^{-ax} \frac{\sin x} {x} dx $

Comment: @ChemstryGeek Maybe this is related topic: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781398/derivative-of-integral-with-variable-bounds/781433

Comment: @Sunghee Yun I don't think it is. I edited my post so that it is more clear what I am asking about.

Comment: What is the downvote for?

Comment: The link is behind a log-in wall

Comment: @user27182 For me it works and I am not logged in. Anyway, with my edit this should be intelligible without the whole article

Comment: @ChemistryGeek got it thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that as $a \to \infty$,

$$0 \leqslant \left|\int_0^\infty e^{-ax} \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx  \right| \leqslant \int_0^\infty e^{-ax} \left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right| \, dx \leqslant\int_0^\infty e^{-ax} = \frac{1}{a} \to 0$$

We can also justify switching the limit and integral by the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) or simply by the uniform convergence of the improper integral.

Comment: Thank you for the elementary approach! How do you actually apply the theorems you mentioned? I know the DCT, but doesn't it work only for sequences of functions?

Comment: @ChemistryGeek: We can apply the DCT for any sequence $a_n$ such that $a_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.  Here we have $e^{-x}$ as an integrable dominating function.  Hence $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^\infty f(x,a_n) \, dx  = \int_0^\infty \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x,a_n) \, dx$.  Since this is true for any sequence it allows us to switch integral and limit as $a \to \infty$.