# Calculate the derivative of an integral with x in both bounds

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I have the following problem:

Let $f(x) = \int_{e^{3x}}^{2x^2}\ln(t)dt$. Evaluate $f'(x)$ at $x = 1$

My approach is to directly calculate the integral using integration by parts, and then just take the derivative of the result and compute it at $x=1$.

I feel like there may be a quicker way using the Fundamental theorem of Calculus but I am not sure. Is my approach correct and is there another approach to this question? Thank you!

Comment: Use Leibnitz's formula.

Comment: Write it as $F(2x^2 ) - F({\rm e}^{3x} )$ with $F(x) = \int_{\rm 1}^x {\ln (t){\rm d}t}$, then use the chain rule and the FTC.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781398/derivative-of-integral-with-variable-bounds See formula in general for this in first answer.

Comment: Based on calculus on many variables and linearity of derivations, consider  each occurrence of x as a different variable $x_i$,  do the differntial and  add all coefficients $$d/dx f(x,x) = ( df(x,y)/dx + df(x,y)/dy )  /.   y\to x $$